# How to CREATING A SERVICE FOR MAC OS X on Xcode5

Tags: macos, service, applescript, automator

I want to create a small service for mac os x. I followed from this link http://simx.me/technonova/tips/creating_a_service_for_mac_os_x.html but i'm stuck at step number 12. Please guide me how to do sample service for mac os x with XCode5. The above tutorial is on XCode3, so please provide step by step process to develop service.

Comment: Besides posting the link, you should make clear how for you got with your project. Try posting some code, even if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: My service is working good, i followed the  below link http://mschade.me/post/37615877537/creating-a-mac-os-x-service-part-i
 But, my question is how to add this service to my mac app, when i install the service it will work automatically, on startup.

Answer (score 0):

That guide is too old to use btw.

You can distribute your service by installing it in ~/Library/Services
or by providing it to the user to double-click, which will prompt if they'd like to install it.